# Program can't print entire array of strings in C but it either prints nothing or only the first character. What is wrong?

Tags: arrays, c

I want this array to print all the elements in this code but it doesn't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "student_info.h"
int main()
{
    char animals[3];
    animals[0] = "lion";
    animals[1] = "Cat";
    numbers[2] = "Tiger";
    printf("%s", numbers[2]);
}
```

Comment: You might want to enable warnings in your compiler and read them. This code appears to have several problems that most compilers would detect.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate your observations.

Comment: I did some editing, barely resisting the temptation to change `numbers` to `animals`. Please review and [edit].

Comment: @Yunnosch Well, sometimes numbers are animals, dangerous ones.

Comment: @Tarik right - I don't trust any cats:)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `numbers` -> `animals`....

You declare an array of three single `char`s. `char animals[3];`

Then you attempt to write "strings" (there actually is no such thing in C) to places where only single chars are possible. `animals[0] = "lion";`
And you should get lots of warnings like

```
main.c:7:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     animals[0] = "lion";
```

Reading compiler warnings closely and treating them as errors is a habit I recommend adopting.

This one means that `"lion"` is a pointer to an (unchangeable) 0-terminated sequence of `char`s in memory. And you are trying to write that pointer into basically a `char` variable, where `char` is one of the types which for the compiler is a narrow integer.

Your code makes some sense if you change your array to store pointer to characters.

```
char* animals[3];
```

That matches how you init it and how you print it, with `"%s"` which is for pointers to 0-terminated sequences of characters, the closest thing C has to strings.

That code (remember the numbers...) gets you no warnings here
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php
and an output of:

```
Tiger
```

For your goal to print all entries in the array you need to understand that C does not have inbuilt support of `printf()` for arrys of "strings" (it "barely" manages char-sequences...).
So you will have to implement a loop yourself. That also gives you control over how it prints, one string per line, all in one line, what in between...

Comment: Not discussing wrong main prototype and unneeded includes...

Answer (score 1):

You should have declared an array of array of char. What you have is an array of char that hold an individual character each.

```
const char *animals[3];
animals[0] = "Lion";
animals[1] = "Tiger";
animals[2] = "Wolf";
```

Another way to do it is:

```
char animals[3][10] = {
                     "Lion",
                     "Tiger",
                     "Wolf"
                 };
```

Working demo of both approaches:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char *animals1[3];
    animals1[0] = "Lion";
    animals1[1] = "Tiger";
    animals1[2] = "Wolf";
    
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", animals1[i]);


    char animals2[3][10] = {
                     "Lion",
                     "Tiger",
                     "Wolf"
                 };
                 
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", animals2[i]);
                 
}
```

See [Online Demo](https://www.onlinegdb.com/sJ_w8_o_H)

Comment: You have to allocate memory for the strings. This will not work.

Comment: @MatteoGalletta In the 1st or 2nd example?

Comment: I commented before you edited the post. The first one anyway. I have just run the Online Demo and I don't understand how it's possible to be honest. I also noticed you're not even using strcpy().

Comment: @MatteoGalleta Well I have an array of pointers that's declared to be of size 3 elements. Each element contains the address of the first byte of each of the strings that are assigned to it. C in all of its glory. BTW I assume you are Italian. I am fond of Italy and it's history, in particular the Roman Empire.

Comment: Yes, what I want to say is the pointers of the strings are not allocated. The only thing allocated are the three pointers, but not the strings. Also, you're assigning strings with `=`, in C you should use strcpy(), I guess. Yes, I am Italian, happy to hear that :).

Comment: @MatteoGalletta AFAIK, the strings are constants and are already statically allocated. All the assignment does is to assign the address of the first byte of each to each array pointer element. I believe this is correct. However, if I wanted to copy each string then, I would first have to allocate the appropriate space prior to the copy.

Comment: Okay, now I understand your point. Thanks for clarification.